# Consolidate max max-msp maxmsp tags

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, tag-synonym-request

As far as I can tell, [max](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/max) [max-msp](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/max-msp) and [maxmsp](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maxmsp) are currently independent tags, but all refer to the same software.

Answer (score 2):

I agree completely; I don't think there are any other topics those terms can refer to in a sound context. I've suggested [max](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/max) and [maxmsp](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maxmsp) as synonyms for [max-msp](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/max-msp) and would like to see others' opinions as well. I thought this made the most sense to me.

edit: It sounds like [there exists another Max program](http://sbooth.org/Max/) used for file conversions that has no relation to Max/MSP. If we need to differentiate, I'd be in favor of avoiding the [max](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/max) tag (and retagging when necessary) in favor of [max-msp](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/max-msp) and maybe an "sbooth-max" tag or something like it.

Answer (score 0):

agreed, there is however a very handy app also called max that I use regurarly for batch conversion of audiofiles. can we add a tag for that? i've actually included it in a question a while back.

Comment: this was my question: http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/20032/multicore-mp3-encoder-for-osx-is-it-available-why-not
'max' in one of the ansers and it actually helped me resolve the issue. how can i close this question and add the tag for max in a proper manner.

Comment: I didn't realize there was another program sharing the Max name, since Max/MSP is pretty popular. Currently we have [9 questions tagged max](http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/max), all of which refer to Max/MSP. It is very easy to retag them. I don't think SE has a clear solution for ambiguous tags for future questions though... do we currently have any other questions about Max-the-conversion-program?